# How to create StringComparer for different languages in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, coreclr

I'm trying to retarget a portable C# library for .Net core 1.0.

I used to do something like this to get a string comparer for a different language, once I obtained a CultureInfo object for the language (via a delegate set by the caller):

```
IComparer<T> comparer = (IComparer<T>)StringComparer.Create(cultureInfo, caseInsensitive);
```

.Net Core currently seems to only support it for the current culture via properties like StringComparer.CurrentCulture.

Is there a way to get a string comparer for a given language or culture?

This is important for an app that uses multiple languages simultaneously, such as an app for language-learning.

Comment: Consider reporting this limitation on GitHub. Maybe it was just an oversight. Looks like it.

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://dotnet.github.io/api/System.StringComparer.html):

> Each call to the `CurrentCulture` property get accessor returns a new `StringComparer` object, as the following code shows.

So, you could set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to the desired culture, then grab the `StringComparer` for that culture using `StringComparer.CurrentCulture`, then set the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to the next desired culture, then grab another `StringComparer` ... etc.

Answer (score 2):

`StringComparer.Create` was added in .NET Standard 2.0, so you can just use it now.

However, if you want to target earlier versions, the following works in .NET Standard 1.0.  It provides the same functionality, by encapsulating the `CompareInfo` (which is available) in a class that implements the `IComparer<string>` interface.

```
public class CultureAwareStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private readonly CompareOptions _options;
    private readonly CompareInfo _compareInfo;

    public CultureAwareStringComparer(CultureInfo culture, CompareOptions options)
    {
        _options = options;
        _compareInfo = culture.CompareInfo;
    }

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return _compareInfo.Compare(x, y, _options);
    }
}
```